# Elsarticle: problems with appendix

Tags: appendices, elsarticle, journal

I use (`elsarticle.cls`) for writing a journal paper for Elsevier journal. I used the code:

```
\appendix
\section{Proposition \ref{p:1}}
\label{sec:app}
```

but I obtained the result:

[image]

This is not the desired result because I would like to obtain something like `Proposition A.1` or `Proposition 1`, but not `Proposition Appendix A.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\section{Proposition}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```